# How to run tests in androidTest module?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, junit, kotlin-multiplatform

In my `build.gralde.kts` there is a module description

```
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation(AndroidTestDependencies.junit)
            }
        }
```

but in the project hierarchy it looks different than commonTest/commonMain etc. Besides, for some reason I can't run the test in this module. What could be the problem?
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set junit dependency like this:

```
val androidTest by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
        implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    }
}
```

In my case it works fine